# Could there be such a thing as a universal logical language?

Tags: logic, language, concept

That is, are there certain conceptual primitives, such as *object*, *action*, *structure*, *property*, *logic*, *event*, *quantity*, *partial*, *paradox*, *system*, *concept*, etc, or  connectives/judgements, such as *for all*, *in which*, *or*, *false*, *there exists*, *such that*, *true,* *and*, etc that rather than being merely tools to discuss concrete matters of logic and mathematics are **themselves** invariant and as such matters of study in their own right, and admissible to a concrete semantic model (or set thereof)?

Comment: by "universal", do you mean shared by philosophers or do you mean that captures everything ?

Comment: Cross-posting (http://linguistics.stackexchange.com/questions/17163/could-there-be-such-a-thing-as-a-universal-logical-language) is discouraged by SE (http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/64068/is-cross-posting-a-question-on-multiple-stack-exchange-sites-permitted-if-the-qu ). You're supposed to pick one SE and post there -- not every SE that might work.

Comment: The question is equally pertinent in both fields. I fail to see the harm in posting in both.

Comment: not sure I understand the question, but perhaps  Anna Wierzbicka and her Natural semantic metalanguage (both in wikipedia) are relevant...

Answer (score 3):

If such a universal logical language exists, it would be subject to some very peculiar limitations which were developed by Alfred Tarski.  His [undefinability](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tarski's_undefinability_theorem) theorem puts some very interesting limitations on such a language.  In particular he considered a language which:

- Is a formal language (its particularly hard to provide a concrete semantic model for non-formal languages)
- Was self referential (necessarily for arguing that a language is truly universal.)
- Contains a negation operator (we like to think negation exits in logic, so its a reasonable requirement)
- Is powerful enough to prove all the truths in arithmetic (otherwise discussing matters of mathematics could be tricky)

**He demonstrated that any such language cannot define its own semantics.**  He argued that, to define its own semantics, such a language would need to define a `True(n)` predicate which returns true if and only if `n` was some form of a sentence in that language.  His particular proof involved encoding a sentence using Godel numbers, and making `True(n)` be a predicate that accepts a number as an argument.  He then used the diagonalization lemma to demonstrate that there must exist a sentence which is true but `True(n)` is false.

There are a few subtle limits.  Dan Willard, for example, explored mathematical systems where multiplication was not a total function, which was just enough of a tweak to prevent the diagonalization lemma from being proven in the language.  However, those systems are not as mainstream as the ones you and I learned in school.

Now, amusingly enough, this suggests that the semantics of English may not be fully sufficient for us to agree upon what "logic" and "mathematics" are, semantically, so I cannot claim this proves that such a universal language cannot exist.  However, hopefully those limitations provided by Tarski will help you explore your own answer to the question.